# CUDA Devices not showing up in "Render" tab (v. 2.78)

Tags: rendering, gpu

I've gone into user settings > system and enabled both of my SLI GPUs for compute devices, however, as per the instructions, there is no "Device" drop-down to select a device in the render tab.

I have the newest version of CUDA as well as up-to-date GPU drivers. Do I need to install/configure blender for specific GPU support to enable this?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Disable SLI, blender works better if the GPUs render in parallel. GPU render works only in cycles, make sure you are in the correct rendering engine.

Comment: @cegaton I've tried with SLI disabled. Cycles is also enabled. The option still does not show up in the Render tab.

Comment: @cegaton Edited. I can't add a third link, but the render tab looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/lNmx0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the cycles render engine:

On the info window

[image]

Select Cycles Render

[image]

and enable GPU Compute Device:

[image]